# NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription remove warning application uses geolocation

Tags: ios, objective-c, cllocationmanager

I created an application in one of view displays the distance from the user to the marker on the map. Ios 8.3 I had to insert the following line info.plist

```
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string></string>
```

because without this line application does not start geolocation.But if you minimize the application,top of the screen will be a warning "app "myapp" uses geolocation". How do I remove this warning?

this is my code

```
self.myLocationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
[self.myLocationManager startUpdatingLocation];

[GMSServices provideAPIKey:@"####"];
GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:59.93 longitude:30.35 zoom:9];
mapView_ = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];
mapView_.settings.compassButton = YES;
mapView_.settings.myLocationButton = YES;
mapView_.myLocationEnabled = true;
//  mapView_.showsUserLocation = YES;
//mapView_.settings.myLocationButton = YES;
mapView_.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
mapView_.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200);
mapView_.center = self.view.center;
[self.scrollView addSubview:mapView_];
```

**UPDATE**
This is not a screenshot, but looks something like this when I fold the application
[image]

Comment: Are you talking about the UIAlertView presented by iOS ? If so, you cannot remove this.

Comment: No, I'm talking about prevention in the menu iphone

Comment: I don't understand... Do you have a screenshot ?

Comment: You cannot remove that bar, it's made  by iOS so that users are aware they have an active app that is using their location.

Comment: @CW0007007 ok, but can i stop a location when user hide application? for that would bar did not show

Comment: Yes if you aren't using the location ... but then you won't get location updates. As long as that's ok. go for it.

Comment: @CW0007007 but how can i stop location when hide app and start when open app?

Comment: Use the AppDelegate methods applicationWillResignActive: & applicationWillEnterForeground:

Answer (score 2):

The blue bar is a new blue status bar for apps that opt to request “When In Use” permission to let them know the app is currently getting continuous location data in the background.

You can read more about it here: http://9to5mac.com/2014/06/04/apple-improves-location-services-in-ios-8-with-when-in-use-mode-visit-monitoring/

You can not get rid of the bar but if you're using When In Use it will vanish after a few seconds.

Comment: but without `<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>` geo in app don't work, can you tell me how can i change this code to a bar did not show up?

Comment: If you're using location services on an app prior to leaving it in iOS8 this bar will show up, you can not avoid it. It is a good thing for the users to be aware the app is using location services.

Comment: ok, but can i stop a location when user hide application? for that would bar did not show

Answer (score 0):

a) don't leave the description empty. that's a hack and may get you rejected. write something sensible

b) you CANT get the bar to disappear IF your app runs in the background and uses location data
=> you can call stopUpdating and stop all mapviews to make it clear you don't need location data
=> your user can force-close the app :D

Comment: ok, but can i stop a location when user hide application? for that would bar did not show